# IOS How to create tableview with two column first column have one row and second column have multiple row ?

Tags: ios, gridview, tableview

Hello here i attach a image i have to create tableview like this image . 
Description: In tableview have two columns first is time and second is event show its come from web services. I don't have idea how to create this type of view .
[image]

if you know any example please share with me . i have find lots of grid view example but the problem is in grid view both column are equal but i have to create first(time) columns height depend on second column(Event) height is equal to this 
Please share your valuable knowledge . Thankyou

Comment: Create two different tableviews, one for the left column and the other one for the right events column. You might also want to consider using UICollectionView and use custom layout.

Comment: when i use two different tableview is't not scroller equally

Answer (score 0):

As k6sandeep suggests, you can put two table-view controllers next to each other.

Assuming your data is available when loading the table views, you can count the amount of events in a time-slot and use this value to size the rows in the left column (in heightForRowAtIndexPath). Then populate the events table as usual.

Using the UIScrollView delegate methods (scrollviewDidScroll) of the tableviews you can synchronise their scrolling behaviour.

An alternative would be to have a collectionview instead of tableviews.

Answer (score 0):

Nishant Chandwani, **UICollectionView in conjunction with UICollectionViewLayout** are designed for complex grids as in you have in your case.

You can subclass UICollectionViewLayout to implement any layout you can imagine. It gives you control over cells' heights and other properties you may need to customize.

[Link to UICollectionViewLayout documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayout)

[Example 1](https://github.com/SureCase/WaterfallCollectionView)

[Example 2](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

While it may look difficult from the first sight after you read methods' names and some example code you will see that everything is pretty straightforward.